# Binary Search Tree preorder traversal, recursion vs loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm

**we can traverse the binary search tree through recursion like:**

```
void traverse1(node t) {
    if( t != NULL) {
        visit(t);
        traverse1(t->left);
        traverse1(t->right);
    }
}
```

**and also through loop( with stack) like:**

```
void traverse2(node root) {
    stack.push(root);
    while (stack.notEmpty()) {
        node next = stack.pop();
        visit(next);
        if (next->right != NULL)
            stack.push(next->right);
        if (next->left != NUll)
            stack.push(next->left)
    }
}
```

**Question**

Which one is more efficiency? why?

I think these two method time complexity is both O(n). so all the differences are all in the space complexity or ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on how you define efficiency?  It is in runtime, amount of code, size of executable, how much memory/stack space is used, or how easy it is to understand the code?

The recursion is very easy to code, hopefully easy to understand, and is less code. Looping may be a bit more complex (depending on how you view complexity) and code.  Recursion may be easier to understand and will be less in the amount of code and in executable size.  Recursion will use more stack space assuming you have a few items to transverse.

Looping will have a larger amount of code (as your above example shows), and could possibly be considered a bit more complex.  But the transverse is just one call to be place on the stack, rather than several. So if you have a lot of items to transverse, loop will be faster as you don't have the time to push items on the stack and the pop them off, which is what will occur when using recursion.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to measure the difference to know for sure. I personally have a feeling that the recursive formulation will beat the one with an explicit stack in this particular instance.

What the non-recursive version has going for it is that it eliminates the calls. On the other hand - depending on the exact library implementation - the pushes and the pop might also resolve to function calls.

Any decent compiler will actually encode your recursive function in a way similar to the following pseudo-code:

```
void traverse1(node t) {
1:
    if( t != NULL) {
        visit(t);
        traverse1(t->left);
        t = t->right;
        goto 1;
    }
}
```

Thus eliminating one of the recursive calls. This is known as tail call elimination.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions have the same space and time complexity.

The recursion implicitly uses *the stack* (memory location) for storing call context, and the second uses a stack abstract data type effectively emulating the first version, using stack explicitly.

The difference is that with the first version, you risk stack overflow with deep, unbalanced trees, however it's simpler conceptually (less opportunities for bugs). The second uses dynamic allocation for storing the pointers to parent nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from efficiency, if your tree is too deep or if your stack space is limited, you may run into overflow - stack overflow!!

With iterative approach, you can use the much larger heap space to place the allocated stack. With recursion, you don't have a choice as the stack frames are pushed and popped for you.

I know that such constrained stack environments may be a bit rare; nevertheless, one needs to be aware of it.

Answer (score -2):

The time and space complexity are the same. The only difference is that `traverse2` doesn't call itself recursively. This *should* make it slightly faster, as pushing/popping from a stack is a cheaper operation than calling a function.

That said, I think the recursive version is "cleaner", so I'd personally use that, unless it turns out to be too slow in practice.